# Terminal: limit my bandwidth

Tags: internet

Is it possible in Yosemite to limit my downloading bandwidth use to for example 300kbps using the terminal? I dont want to install software to do this.

Comment: This is hard to answer the way it has been asked. Downloading from what? A specific site? Using a specific protocol? All inbound traffic on a specific interface? Maybe you can describe your problem instead of asking for a specific solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is similar question (with answers :)), hopefully this will help: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3859/limit-bandwidth-on-a-per-app-basis-on-os-x